# php trying to get value for $_post['value .$i

Tags: php

so I have several post items like value1 value2 value3

I need to get value of each, all this outputs is $_POST["value1"] instead of the number in the value, any ideas?

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
$itemamount = '$_POST/["amount' . $i . '"/]';
$itemprice = '$_POST/["price' . $i . '"/]'; 
$itemamount = str_replace("/","",$itemprice);
$itemprice = str_replace("/","",$itemamount);;
echo $itemamount . '<br /><br />';
$itemtotal = $itemprice*$itemamount;
```

Comment: Consider using form fields with names like `amount[0]`, `amount[1]`, etc. or just `amount[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove single quotes like

```
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $itemamount = $_POST["amount$i"];
    $itemprice = $_POST["price$i"]; 
}
```